# What is correct: 'I did' or 'it did'? (In the given context)

Tags: grammar

Which would be the correct way to form the following sentence:

> "I just had piss shivers so hard that I almost dislocated my jaw."
>   OR
>   "I just had piss shivers so hard that it (they) almost dislocated my jaw."

Also, would it be correct to write it this way:

> "I just had piss shivers so hard that my jaw almost got dislocated."

The problem that I have with the first sentence is that piss shiver isn't something that I did, it's something that happen to me, so is it still "I dislocated my jaw" or do they dislocated my jaw/it got dislocated? "I dislocated my jaw" sounds like I was doing something- eating, talking, piss-shivering. Not having experienced something.

Comment: What do those sentences mean? Are they word for word translations of Ukrainian idioms? Ja usus? I would think the two versions are interchangable if I understand them correctly

Comment: I'd love to know what a piss shiver is.

Comment: @Barrie, piss shiver: http://www.straightdope.com/columns/read/1044/what-causes-piss-shiver

Comment: Thank you. Never heard of the phenomenon, and can't say I've ever consciously experienced it.

Comment: I read the link and still don't really  know what a piss shiver is. Is it real?

Comment: @RoaringFish After finishing a piss, sometimes one feels a whole-body shiver. It's weird. Not unpleasant, but - yes - weird.

Comment: That is what I read, but it has never happened to me or anybody I have asked...

Comment: Well - as embarassing as this comment is going to be - I *have* experienced it many times. Interestingly, only while I'm standing up and doing my thing. I don't really remember it happening to me while sitting. :O

Comment: don't be embarrassed, it's a normal thing. I'm actually weirded out by all those people who don't even know what it is)

Comment: @user51922 just chalk it up under the same rubric as "morning people" versus "night people" - those who have piss shivers just don't understand those who don't - and vice versa.

Comment: Lol! PS user51922 and @HowardPautz, have you guys noticed the standing/sitting thing for yourself?

Comment: @mikhailcazi nope, I'm one of those "who don't" :))

Comment: @user51922 Back to the question, I think the first and third sentence are the most appropriate way to say it. I also don't see anything wrong with the second one (provided you use 'they'). Since '*I just had so much food that it made me sick.*' is correct, why shouldn't your second one be correct, too? :)

Comment: @mikhailcazi First of all- thanks for editing my question and making it more understandable. Can I just write you from time to time and ask ridiculous questions about English language? It's ok if it's not ok. Now to the piss shiver thing:) The problem that I have with the first sentence is that piss shiver isn't something that I did, it's something that happen to me, so is it still  "I dislocated my jaw" or do they dislocated my jaw/it got dislocated? "I dislocated my jaw" sounds like I was doing something- eating, talking, piss-shivering. Not having experienced something.

Comment: Well, I'm no expert as the top accounts are, but sure you can! :) As for your question, I went over it again: The third sentence is correct for sure. The second one is correct too (provided you use *they*). Coming to the first one, now I'm not that sure. It doesn't *sound* wrong to me. I get what you're trying to say, but I don't think it's wrong to write "I dislocated my jaw'.

Comment: Because, in the end, it's *you* who've dislocated their jaw. I think for words like 'dislocated', 'hurt', it's okay to say 'I hurt myself' even though it may be due to an external agent. 'The ball hit me so hard that I hurt myself'. I may be completely wrong here, though. Better confirm with the top accounts here. <Try editing your question (some minor edit) just so it shows in the active questions and gets more views and more people see it and may answer it>

Comment: I don't know how to do that, this is my first time here. I probably should read some FAQ or something. But thank you anyway, at least I know that it's a legitimate question.

Comment: @user51922 Edited it for you, it's back in the active list, but it doesn't seem like people are interested in answering it. Haha :P

Comment: @mikhailcazi Thanks again. I also clarified it further. But maybe people are too prudish to talk about piss shivers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either is correct in this case. According to MW, we can define "dislocate" as:

> to move (a bone) out of its normal location or position in a joint

Since the piss shivers are causing you to jerk your jaw out of place, both you and the shivers can be considered the actor here, and you can say that either one almost dislocated your jaw.

The last sentence ("got dislocated"), while not the most common phrasing, is also correct. "I had piss shivers so hard that I almost suffered a dislocated jaw," is another good phrasing.

But let's answer the deeper philosophical question behind your asking about the piss shivers. Can you say "I dislocated" something if you didn't do anything? I would say yes, in most cases. If a friend of mine (call him Steve) were tackled randomly or struck suddenly by a car and suffered a dislocated joint because of it, it would not be bizarre for me to say "Steve dislocated his pelvis when that guy tackled him" or "Steve dislocated his elbow in the wreck". The only scenario I can conjure in which it seems inappropriate to say that Steve dislocated something is if someone (not Steve) is deliberately, carefully popping Steve's joint out of place.

All in all, if there's even a small element of chance in whether or not something will lead to a dislocation, you can say "I dislocated". However, if you're unsure, making something else the actor is perfectly fine, and we can say that "the wreck dislocated Steve's elbow" or "that guy dislocated Steve's pelvis when he tackled him".

Comment: I think I'm satisfied with this answer, thank you:) I guess it's just the difference between our languages.